# How to get iTunes to automatically scan a folder for new music?

Tags: macos, itunes

I like to buy my music on Amazon.com instead of iTunes, because they sell them in mp3 format. I would like to have iTunes scan the folder created by the Amazon MP3 downloader automatically on startup. I thought iTunes 9 would be able to do that, I saw that it creates a 'Automatically Add to iTunes' folder in its repository, so I tried this (on OSX):

- linking the 'Automatically Add to iTunes' folder to the Amazon MP3 folder
- pointing the Amazon MP3 folder to the 'Automatically Add to iTunes' folder

But iTunes does not seem to pick up any new songs... Possibly because it imports only files that are directly under the 'Automatically Add to iTunes' folder, while the Amazon MP3 downloader organizes files in a Artist/Album/Song hierarchy.

Does anyone know how to get this auto-import done?
Using the menu File -> Add to library works great, but it's not automatic :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you change where the downloads save to? You could chose the automatically add to itunes folder as the source for the downloads from Amazon.

I had just ticked the box to automatically add tracks  to itunes, but this creates duplicates (files in amazon download folder and same files in itunes music directory). It does put the songs automatically in itunes, but the duplication is annoying.

Comment: You know what, I didn't even notice there was a 'Add downloaded tracks to iTunes', and it's right there under the "Save downloads to" field! I can't believe I missed that :) Tried it, but as you say, it creates duplicates... This is not bad, but it would be fantastic if there was a way without the duplicates :)

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for that feature for some time to no avail.

There is certainly a way through the COM API but I am not desperate that much :-)

Answer (score 1):

How did you create the link? In Apple's knowledge base article about the [Automatically Add to iTunes folder](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3832) they say not to use an alias. (Hopefully a symlink would work however).

Comment: I created a symlink using 'ln -s'